# Plug the window or modal directly to file button

Tags: filepicker.io

I am just allow user to upload file via `computer` so I don't really need the pop-up.

Is that possible to plug the `filepicker window` directly to `<input type="file">` so when user click `choose file` button. It direct open OS file window instead of open filepicker ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the filepicker.store() API for exactly this purpose - https://developers.inkfilepicker.com/docs/web/#store

```
var input = document.getElementById("store-input");
filepicker.store(input, function(InkBlob){
        console.log("Store successful:", JSON.stringify(InkBlob));
    }, function(FPError) {
        console.log(FPError.toString());
    }, function(progress) {
        console.log("Loading: "+progress+"%");
    }
);
```